# Converting adjacency list tables to MPTT in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, adjacency-list, mptt

Is there a helpful tool or script resource to aid conversion from old-school adjacency list tables to MPTT?

I would have thought it was a problem faced by a few cleverer souls than I in the past, and thought I'd check here first in case they came up with a clever solution in their travels - before embarking on my own journey to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.honk.com.au/index.php/2010/04/22/convert-adjacency-list-model-to-a-modified-preorder-tree-traversal-mptt-model-hierarchy/) includes code to make the conversion. Look at the bottom for the SQL version of the code (there's also a PHP script to do it).

I know that I've seen code from Joe Celko on how to do it, but I don't recall if that was on the intertubes or in [his book on trees and hierarchies in SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202).